# How to add element with old element's html and remove old element in Jquery with new?

Tags: jquery

I want to add new element by jquery with old element and also remove old element in place of new.

For ex,

```
<div id="a1"> </div>
```

should be like

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
       <td class="Frame_Box_top_left"></td>
       <td class="Frame_Box_top"></td>
       <td class="Frame_Box_top_right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Frame_Box_left"></td>       
       <td class="Frame_Box_inner" valign="top">

                  "new element here !"

       </td>
       <td class="Frame_Box_right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Frame_Box_bottom_left"></td>
       <td class="Frame_Box_bottom"></td>
       <td class="Frame_Box_bottom_right"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can put html in your questions, just select it and hit the 101010 button up top to indent it 4 spaces for formatting (or put the spaces in yourself), the same goes for code.

Comment: It's invalid to have a `div` element directly inside a `table` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to put a new element around an old one, like this:

```
$("#a1").wrap('<div id="new" />');
```

For other cases not working with a single element, there's also [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), and for wrapping contents instead of the element itself, there's [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

Comment: It worked but destroyed all layout. I am using table. Plz help.

Comment: @Neeraj - You need to post your actual markup...if this is causing issues you simplified to example *too* much here, can you paste the actual markup you have?

Comment: Ok, I want to style elements with a box like structure. i used Jq to build plugin. But i am able to insert table after,before,inside the element but not replace it.

Comment: @Neeraj - I'm not following...can you post the actual markup?  You can only place certain elements in a table structure, it depends where you're trying to put something.

Comment: @Neeraj - Yeah...you can't put a `<div>` in a table (it's not a valid child), you can do this: `$("#a1").wrap('<table id="new"><tr><td></td></tr></table>');` to wrap it appropriately, but not sure what that will accomplish?

Comment: Can this be done, add all properties (id, class) to table's 'inner' td and remove old element and add new one ?

Comment: @Neeraj - There's no built-in method for copying *all* attributes no...because they may be invalid, element types have different attributes.

Comment: i did $("#a1").wrap('<table id="new"><tr><td></td></tr></table>'); as $(this).wrap(table_layout); , but all layout destroyed.

Comment: @Neeraj - You're providing almost no relevant information with each update, if you're not showing us the **actual** markup, no one can help.  Do you want to **move** the element? that's what it seems like at this point.

Comment: You were right. Now i am using $(this).empty(); $(this).append(table_layout); . Thanx. It works fine